# C# consume ws-security webservice with ssl and server certificate Could not establish secure channel for SSL/TLS with authority

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, soap-client

I have to consume probably java webservice with SSL certificate and server certificate. I got TLS certificate and WSS certificate

My app.config:

```
<endpoint address="ADDR"
   binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="customB" behaviorConfiguration="myBehavior" contract="ServiceReference1.MyClient" name="Name" >
<identity>
    <dns value="DNS-CERTIFICATE-VALUE"/>
</identity>
```

```
<behavior name="myBehavior">
<clientCredentials supportInteractive="false">
    <clientCertificate findValue="TLS CERT" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" x509FindType="FindByThumbprint" />
    <serviceCertificate>
        <defaultCertificate findValue="WSS CERT" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" x509FindType="FindByThumbprint" />
        <authentication certificateValidationMode="None" revocationMode="NoCheck" trustedStoreLocation="LocalMachine" />
    </serviceCertificate>
</clientCredentials>
```

```
<customBinding>
<binding name="customB">
    <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap11" />
    <security enableUnsecuredResponse="true" authenticationMode="MutualCertificate" includeTimestamp="false" securityHeaderLayout="Lax" allowInsecureTransport="true" 
                messageSecurityVersion="WSSecurity10WSTrustFebruary2005WSSecureConversationFebruary2005WSSecurityPolicy11BasicSecurityProfile10" > </security>
    <httpsTransport />
</binding>
```

In app code I added:

```
 ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += delegate { return true; };
 ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
 ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

And all the time I got error:
**Could not establish secure channel for SSL/TLS with authority ADDR**

I also tried:

```
client.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, "THUMB", false)[0];
```

where THUMB is TLS or WSS cert (checked both)

I also tried to add in Reference.cs before interface:

```
ProtectionLevel = ProtectionLevel.Sign
```

Still no luck. Can you give me any advice? I have working project in Soap UI, where in options I selected SSL cert and in Outgoing WS-Security Configurations added Siganture with certificate (WSS) with Binary Security Token option. It is working perfect.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is here:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/saurabs/2016/03/07/wcf-how-to-send-two-different-client-certificates-as-credentials-at-both-transport-and-message-level/

You have to create custom credentials for transportCertificate and then add it to behavior. There is no standard option to use 3 certificates at the same moment. Provided solution was customized for my project and I am using authenticationMode="MutualCertificate" and in behavior I am using also server certificate. I only customize adding transport certificate, all other things are from base class.